# What I need to know before using Debian repos?

Tags: repository, debian

As example I don't know is Debian Buster and Focal Fossa (20.04) compatible? How to check it? What are another moments of cross compatibility?

What should to know a newcomer who wants to use Debian repositories in Ubuntu?

Comment: No; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the 2020-April release and is made up of packages from Debian *sid*, Debian *testing*, and possibly some Debian *stable*, but also packages from further upstream.  Debian *old stable* (Buster; Bullseye is current *stable*) is from a different year with a different software stack.  Some packages may align perfectly; but the majority will not - thus result is *dependency hell* unless you're very careful, pin & do your homework pre-install, and monitor it from then on (ie. a maintenance burden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You shouldn't.

Don't mix repos from different distributions - they might have different dependencies.

Instead, either uses [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them), or manually install Debian packages (that you have carefully curated and ensured dependency compatibility).

Anything else will probably not end in a good way.

If you really need to use Debian repos, you should use Debian.

*As an example, I've manually installed and used Nano from the Debian sid (unstable) repo for the last 2 years without any issues at all. The dependencies check out, and this ensures I have the latest Nano version available as a `.deb` package, instead of being stuck with the Ubuntu LTS version. Also, this is fairly harmless and easy to rollback if anything unexpected should happen.*

Comment: Thank you! I didn't care for it thinking that dependencies weren't a big problem. Also, I didn't distinguish between PPA and Debian thinking they were compatible by default since Ubuntu is a fork (?). Now I decided to look for a package in PPA and I found it. As a newbie, I often search for packages through google and it gives guides mentioning Debian repositories. That's why I created this question. You set me on the right path.

Comment: That's good to hear. Good luck! 

Comment: Artur, what about security reasons and random PPA's (from unverified maintainers)? What is a most right way to find chromium PPA as example? Without snap?

Comment: First way I go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/web/chromium-browser but there is transitional snap and sources.

Answer (score 3):

No; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the 2020-April release and is made up of packages from Debian *sid*, Debian *testing*, and possibly some Debian *stable*, but also packages from further upstream.

Debian *old stable* (Buster; Bullseye is current *stable*) is from a different year with a different software stack.  Some packages may align perfectly; but the majority will not - thus result is *dependency hell* unless you're very careful, pin & do your homework pre-install, and monitor it from then on (ie. a maintenance burden)

If you're asking the question, you're not ready to fix the problems that are *likely* to occur, if not at first, but sometime into the future  (ie. *aforementioned maintenance burden; ensuring changes haven't occurred or fixing the mess after they've happened*)

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I have been using Linux for 2 years now but I still live with habits from my Windows days.

Comment: FYI:   I often write that I consider Debian & Ubuntu as *equivalent* and drop-in replacements for each other; which is easy given how close they are - but they never *align*.  I'm using Debian *bookworm* right now, yet many packages here are behind my Ubuntu *kinetic* system, others however are actually ahead, whilst the majority are almost identical!.  It's easiest for my chosen release for both given both are development, but even these don't align. LXQt in Debian *bookworm* is equivalent to Lubuntu 21.04 that's EOL; Debian's *experimental* has what Ubuntu *kinetic* has had for weeks

Comment: Why  --   it's the Lubuntu *devs* that are currently pushing upstream the LXQt desktop (from Ubuntu) so they're (*Debian & Ubuntu; Ubuntu being ahead for two releases now*) both back in ~sync as much as possible.. The Lubuntu team has a DD (Debian *developer*), a DM (Debian *maintainer*).... but **never** assume they're always in sync; they are only for parts of the repositories but never it all.

Comment: If a non-Lubuntu/non-LXQt example is needed, my Ubuntu *jammy* box received grub 2.06 in 2021 & I briefly had issues with it there.. Weeks passed, and it wasn't until the following year that grub 2.06 finally reached Debian, and I discovered issues again on my Debian box; enough weeks that I couldn't recall exactly what the fix was without searching online to confirm... Debian maybe upstream of Ubuntu in a huge percentage of packages, but to assume that applies for all (*without checking*) will just lead to problems...